# Is there a way to add the "CanPlaceOn" NBT tag to an item in spigot?

Tags: java, minecraft, spigot

I try to make an item that can be placed in adventure mode in spigot, I know its possible with commands by adding the {CanPlaceOn} NBT tag to the item, but couldn't find a way in spigot

I sadly couldn't really try anything so far since i didnt find anything about it online.

Comment: Welcome on StackOverflow ! Can you give your actual code and tell your spigot version ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll have to use nms for this.

Here's [a thread](https://www.spigotmc.org/threads/adding-canplaceon-nbttag-via-plugin.247846/) from the spigot forum that talks about it. If you aren't too familiar with how the Minecraft code works, or aren't very experienced in java, it might be difficult to set up and use.